# Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Not sure why I am still encountering the issue "Error 1215" wherein they have the same data type and parent table is in primary key.

child table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_notice_type` (
  `CUSTOMER_NOTICE_TYPE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_NOTICE_TYPE_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTOMER_NOTICE_TYPE_ID`),
  KEY `fk_customer_id_customer_notice_type_idx` (`CUSTOMER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_id_customer_notice_type` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`CUSTOMER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=494 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE `system_notice_type` (
  `SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SQL script to create Foreign Key:

```
ALTER TABLE `fexpress`.`customer_notice_type` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_system_notice_type_customer_notice_type` 
FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_ID`) 
REFERENCES `fexpress`.`system_notice_type` (`SYSTEM_NOTICE_TYPE_ID`)
ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two potential problems.  First, the `alter table` statement references `fexpress`.  This may or may not be the correct schema for the table.  So, that is one potential problem.

The second real problem is the constraint defined in the child table:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_id_customer_notice_type` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`) REFERENCES `customer`(`CUSTOMER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The parent table is not yet defined, so it generates an error.

Removing this row and adjusting the schema name results in working code, as in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51da0).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
When you say parent table, are you referring to customer table? If yes, this is already defined and currently working. The issue right now is that I can't add another FK constraint with "system_notice_type" parent table.